# How to format sqlite select output?

Tags: html, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite DB. One table with a key and name and a description columns.
I want to be able to format the data so I can use it in a html select pulldown.
Here's one of the many things I have tried ...

```
sqlite> select * from ppt_branch;
1|smellopment|where everything sucks all the time
2|development|just a mess
3|stage|all the world's a stage
4|production|DO NOT TOUCH IT!
sqlite> select '<option value=' ppt_branch_id '>' from ppt_branch ;
SQL error: near "'>'": syntax error
sqlite>
```

... but as you can see that is not right.  I was hoping for output like ...

```
   <option value='1'>smellopment</option>
   <option value='2'>development</option>
   <option value='3'>stage</option>
   <option value='4'>production</option>
```

... but I am not even close.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: alignment only: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40656/how-to-properly-format-sqlite-shell-output

Answer (score 3):

Well, your language should catch that query result and format it as you want. When you write software cleanly (MVC approach), you *don't* mix data and formatting. It's not just for the possibility of non-web deployment one day, it's primarily to organize your work in specialized logical structures: one for data, one for control, one for viewing.

But here's the way to do it with literals. You were close, you just needed concatenation:

```
SELECT '<option value=''' || ppt_branch_id || '''>' || ppt_branch_name || '</option>' 
FROM ppt_branch;
```