# Assign variable name to sqlite3 query result in bash when <<EOF is used

Tags: bash, shell, sqlite, sh, heredoc

I have a bash script as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /Users/amar/Documents/ThesisCode/CEP_codes/mqtt-receiver

sqlite3 database <<EOF
SELECT sum(detection_time - generation_time)/count(*) from mobile_cep_data;
SELECT ((max(detection_time)- min(detection_time))*1000)/count(*) from mobile_cep_data;
EOF
```

it gives me result as

```
15
12
```

How can I get the result as

```
latency   = 15
thoughput = 12
```

Comment: This might help: [How to format sqlite select output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23120906/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
<<EOF
```

with

```
<<EOF | sed '1s/^/latency   = /;2s/^/thoughput = /'
```

Comment: Nice, using sed here is a smart idea. Thx a ton!

Answer (score 4):

@Cyrus's answer is fine and demonstrates a useful technique, and I've therefore upvoted it, but I'd like to point out that you can also do:

```
sqlite3 database <<EOF
SELECT 'latency   = ',
       sum(detection_time - generation_time)/count(*) from mobile_cep_data;
SELECT 'thoughput = ',
       ((max(detection_time)- min(detection_time))*1000)/count(*) from mobile_cep_data;
EOF
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for letting me know. This code workes too.

Comment: I think this approach is cleaner, portable and more appropriate